# Semantic HTML for article reactions

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I need to create a reaction section for blog posts (think like Facebook reactions), but am wondering if the markup I've chosen is semantically correct. Would reactions fall under the `<aside>` tag in an `<article>`?

I decided to use a the `<figure>` element with a `<figcaption>` for the name of the reaction. Right now it's just a mock using emojis, but in the future it would probably be an svg/img element.

For the number of people reacting, I've decided to use the `<output>` element. This number will increment when a user clicks on the reaction.

I'm not sure if my choices are semantically correct and would love to get some feedback. I was hesitant to use `<output>` in the `<figure>` tag but it states in [MDN that flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure) is permitted in `<figure>` tag.

```css
.reactions {
  list-style: none; 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
figure {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
```

```html
<article>
  <header>
    <h1>Me article heading</h1>
  </header>
  <section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta quos, voluptatem ab aliquam perspiciatis magnam a ullam aspernatur neque unde similique omnis doloremque at, sit dolorum natus velit dolores. Illo.</p>
  </section>
  <aside>
     <ul class="reactions">
          <li>
            <figure>
              <figcaption>Like</figcaption>
              
              <output>16</output>
            </figure>
          </li>
          <li>
            <figure>
              <figcaption>Sad</figcaption>
              
              <output>50</output>
            </figure>
          </li>
          <li>
            <figure>
              <figcaption>Angry</figcaption>
              
              <output>0</output>
            </figure>
          </li>
          <li>
            <figure>
              <figcaption>Wow</figcaption>
              
              <output>234</output>
            </figure>
          </li>
          <li>
            <figure>
              <figcaption>LOL</figcaption>
              
              <output>9</output>
            </figure>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </aside>
</article>
```

Comment: Are you only displaying the interactions, not not providing a way for users to add their own interactions? Facebook's approach does both.

Answer (score 0):

You could place it in a [`footer` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/sections.html#the-footer-element), as it’s for "information about its section". Inside this `footer`, you could keep using the `aside` element if the reaction lists warrants a section.

```html
<article>
  <h1>Me article heading</h1>

  <footer>
    <aside>
      <h2>Reactions</h2>
      <!-- reaction list -->
    </aside>
  </footer>

</article>
```

Instead of an `ul` element, you could use a [`dl` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element), which conveys that each list entry consists of a label and a value.

```html
<dl>

  <dt>Sad <span></span></dt>
  <dd>50</dd>

  <dt>Angry <span></span></dt>
  <dd>0</dd>

</dl>
```

This doesn’t allow you to use `figure`+`figcaption`, though (except only for the label and the icon), but I don’t think it adds useful semantics in this context anyway.

While the [`output` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/sec-forms.html#the-output-element) seems to fit according to its definition ("the result of a user action"), I don’t think it’s a good fit in this context -- but it’s hard to say for sure.

What could be helpful is providing a label that makes clear that these are the numbers of the reactions. If the label shouldn’t be visible on the page, you could consider using `aria-label`.